# How do I say I just got well from a fever yesterday?

Tags: word-usage, verbs, sentence

Scenario: for example I had a fever for the past two days. After my fever broke I went to hang out with friends where they planned on going to the beach or any activity that involves cold water. Now when they insist how can I casually say that I just recovered from a fever without sounding dramatic ? Thank you!

Comment: “My fever ended [time expression]”

Answer (score 1):

- "No thanks, I just got over a cold." (Depends on what caused the
  fever of course.)
- "No thanks, I'm a bit under the weather."
- "No thanks, I'm getting over something."

Source: I'm a native English speaker.

Comment: The thing is, some of your suggestions could lead me to believe that you are still sick (e.g. under the weather) Especially in this Covid-19 era I would want to make sure that I conveyed that I am not sick anymore but I’m not feeling 100% yet either.  Maybe “No thanks. I’m still not feeling up to that after my cold”  or “No thanks, even though my cold is gone I’m still not at 100%”

Answer (score 1):

Fever is a symptom of infection, caused by an immune system response to the infection. You can simply tell your friends, "Sorry, I've been sick and want to wait until I'm sure it's safe." With the coronavirus pandemic happening, I'm sure they will understand. In the above scenario, don't feel like you need to communicate to them they you've had a fever. The really useful thing for them to know is that you've recently been sick and are worried you might still be contagious.